# comparing two int values in tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How would I go about getting a value from a column in a table and compare it to a column in another table and return the greater of the two in a single query?

I have two different queries for getting those values, I just don't know how to compare:

```
select level from cmh where user = 'blah'
select level from cons where user = 'blah'
```

I need to compare the above two levels and get the greater of the two.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like (off the top of my head)

```
select
case when cmh.level > cons.level 
then cmh.level
else cons.level
end
from cmh inner join cons on cmh.[user] = cons.[user]
where cons.[user] = 'blah'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use UNION to join the two queries and then use MAX() to get the greater of the levels.

```
select max(level) as level
from (
     select level from cmh where user = 'blah'
     union all
     select level from cons where user = 'blah'
     ) as result
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are not relatable (or if you're comparring two different users, etc.) then one way you could do it:

```
Declare @var1 as int
Declare @var2 as int

SET @var1 = (select level from cmh where user = 'blah')
SET @var2 = (select level from cons where user = 'blah')

SELECT
CASE WHEN isnull(@var1,0) >= isnull(@var2,0) THEN @var1 ELSE @var2 END
```

Otherwise, you could relate the tables to get an entire dataset back like this:

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN isnull(T1.level,0) >= isnull(T2.level,0) THEN @var1 ELSE @var2 END as [greatest]
FROM
   cmh T1 LEFT JOIN cons T2
   ON T1.user = T2.user
WHERE T1.user = 'blah'
```